# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dropbox, desire2learn

I am trying to extract data from D2L for the dropbox submissions using API's I have a link which returns a Json Array as per told [on the documentation](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html#get--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-dropbox-folders-(folderId)-submissions-) and from this Array I just need the Id feild nothing else.

I have tried to convert this Array into dynamic Object but that didn't help.

Here is my code.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://" + LMS_URL);
var authenticator = new ValenceAuthenticator(userContext);
string Link = "/d2l/api/le/1.12/UnitID/dropbox/folders/UniID/submissions/";
var request = new RestRequest(string.Format(Link));
request.Method = Method.GET;

authenticator.Authenticate(client, request);

var response = client.Execute(request);

string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content);
Response.Write(jsonString);

//var splashInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectD>(response.Content);
 dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

var parsedObject = jsonResponse.Parse(jsonResponse);
string json = jsonResponse;
var popupJson = parsedObject["id"].ToString();
```

What my goal is that grab the list of ID's from this response and loop through them, these ID's are the key for my next API route.

Here is a glance at what I get from the response:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 2021,
    "CategoryId": null,
    "Name": "Graded Assignment:  Part 1",
    "CustomInstructions": {
      "Text": "Directions:\r\nCOMPLETE the following TestOut Activities\r\n\r\n1.2.10 Practice Questions\r\n1.3.8 Practice Questions\r\n\r\nGo to TestOut to complete the Assignment."
      //Other properties omitted
    }
    //Other properties omitted
  }
]
```

Comment: Why are you parsing the response *twice*?  Also you sample JSON is not well-formed, it appears to be truncated after the value of `CustomInstructions.Text`.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error.  Is your JSON really truncated, or did you omit the remainder from your question?

Comment: Hi @dbc The JSON has the ending `}` after the full-text note, Its a really big text I didn't want to post it al but yes it does closes with the proper `}`
For the Parsing it twice, I am only doing it once, the second one is I using the same Parsing just adding what feild that I want "id"

Comment: Are you sure the JSON shown in the question reflects the *top level schema* of the JSON returned?  Your doc link says *This action retrieves a JSON array of EntityDropbox structures*, and [Dropbox.EntityDropbox](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html#Dropbox.EntityDropbox) doesn't look like what you show in your question.  In fact it looks like [`Dropbox.DropboxFolder`](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html#Dropbox.DropboxFolder) which is returned by a different API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost container in the JSON returned is an array, so you need to deserialize to a collection type as specified in the Newtonsoft's *[Serialization Guide: IEnumerable, Lists, and Arrays](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Lists)*.

Since you only care about the `Id` property of the object(s) in the array, you can use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) to deserialize just the interesting value(s):

```
var ids =  JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content, new [] { new { Id = default(long) } })
    .Select(o => o.Id)
    .ToList();
```

And if you are *certain* the outermost array will contain exactly one item, you can do:

```
var id =  JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content, new [] { new { Id = default(long) } })
    .Select(o => o.Id)
    .Single();
```

Alternatively, if you think you will later need to deserialize additional properties, you could make an explicit data model as follows:

```
public class ObjectId
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

And do:

```
var ids =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjectId>>(response.Content)
    .Select(o => o.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Notes:

- You will need to determine from the API documentation whether `long` or `int` is more appropriate for the `Id` value.
- As a general rule I recommend not parsing to `dynamic` because you lose compile-time checking for correctness.  When dealing with completely free-form JSON, parsing to `JToken` may be a better solution -- but your JSON appears to have a fixed schema, so neither is necessary.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sr5Fts).

Comment: This worked, thank you so much, the Demo helped alot as well, Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @dbc  I have a question about the above issue, I have a second object that I want to grab from this Json, how can I do so, I created the Class for the whole Json Object but it gives me an Error

Comment: @Maxi - you should ask another question and include a [mcve] as well as the full `ToString()` output of the exception.  I can't really tell the problem just from a comment.